# What is the phase difference between phases in 3phase system, if system becomes unbalanced

Tags: power, voltage-measurement, three-phase, network, system

[image]Is the phase difference between the voltage phase 120 degree in an unbalanced system if not what how can we calculate it?

I will try to explain this a litte more clearly.
[image]

More specifically in this case:
[image]

P.s I understand what changes need to be done mathematical but does the change in voltage actually cause change in phase between  Phase Voltages.

Comment: depends of the loads. just the dividers. could be up to 208V.

Comment: If you'll show what you have tried, people will be able to point out exactly where you got it wrong, or where to help you. Otherwise some might think you're trying to get them solve homeworks for free (which this site doesn't do).

Comment: Hey, i have edited with a better explanation of what I am failing to understand.

Comment: Use Fortescue method https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetrical_components

Answer (score 1):

Here is what happens when default "neutral" occurs at "user" loads.
Note that "earth" is always wired for "safety".

[image]

Edit: Case of OP question

When voltages are not equal (unbalanced voltages system), one can use also the Fortescue Method.
We then obtain Homopolar, Direct and Inverse system generators.
With these 3 "systems", calculate the variables needed.
Then, Use the inverse Fortescue transform to get true variables.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetrical_components